# SQL Server - Delete rows from one side of a JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that identifies orphaned rows in one table after joining it to another.  The query I have for selecting the rows that need to be deleted works fine, and properly selects the rows that need to be deleted:

```
select  fl.Request_ID as Check_RID, 
        fl.J_Number as Check_JID, 
        rh.request_ID, 
        rh.J_Number

from        Route_Legs_Route_Header rh
left join   Request_Route_Legs fl on fl.Request_ID = rh.Request_ID AND fl.J_Number = rh.J_Number

where   rh.Route_ID <> 0
AND     fl.Request_ID is null
```

My question is, now that I've selected which rows need to be deleted, how do I use this join to actually delete the rows from `Route_Legs_Route_Header`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should write the query as:

```
DELETE FROM rh
FROM Route_Legs_Route_Header AS rh
left join  Request_Route_Legs fl on fl.Request_ID = rh.Request_ID 
AND fl.J_Number = rh.J_Number
where   rh.Route_ID <> 0
AND     fl.Request_ID is null
```

The `From` clause with the join operator will be evaluated first. Then the `Delete` clause will delete the rows from `rh` alias i.e. the table from the join `Route_Legs_Route_Header`. 
Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, you can delete from a table alias. This comes handy when you already have a working query, like you do:

```
delete rh
from Route_Legs_Route_Header rh
left join Request_Route_Legs fl 
    on fl.Request_ID = rh.Request_ID and fl.J_Number = rh.J_Number
where rh.Route_ID <> 0 and fl.Request_ID is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a temptable if I were you like below:

```
select  fl.Request_ID as Check_RID, 
        fl.J_Number as Check_JID, 
        rh.request_ID, 
        rh.J_Number

INTO #RowsToDelete

from        Route_Legs_Route_Header rh
left join   Request_Route_Legs fl on fl.Request_ID = rh.Request_ID AND fl.J_Number = rh.J_Number

where   rh.Route_ID <> 0
AND     fl.Request_ID is null

DELETE FROM Route_Legs_Route_Header
WHERE request_ID in (Select Request_ID from #temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer an *updatable cte* in such cases:

First I create a *mockup scenario* to simulate your issue:

```
DECLARE @tblParent TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,SomeValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tblParent VALUES('Row 1'),('Row 2');

DECLARE @tblChildren TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, ParentID INT,SomeValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tblChildren VALUES(1,'Child 1.1'),(1,'Child 1.2')
                              ,(2,'Child 2.1')
                              ,(3,'Orphan');
```

--This query is - in principles - your approach:
--Add the table alias `ch` to the `*` to reduce the set on rows solely from `@tblChildren`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM @tblChildren ch
LEFT JOIN @tblParent p ON p.ID=ch.ParentID
WHERE p.ID IS NULL;
```

--This query is - at least for me - easier to read and does the same:

```
SELECT * FROM @tblChildren ch
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @tblParent p WHERE p.ID=ch.ParentID);
```

--We can place the last query into a cte's body and delete its resultset:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT * FROM @tblChildren ch
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @tblParent p WHERE p.ID=ch.ParentID)
)
DELETE FROM cte;
```

--Check it out, the orphan is gone:

```
SELECT * FROM @tblChildren ch
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @tblParent p WHERE p.ID=ch.ParentID);
```